# Translation issue in Sonata Admin

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a translation feature on my website implemented using the doctrine-extensions-bundle, and everything seems to work fine except one thing: in Sonata admin panel, I encounter the following issue:

[image]

In the database, the text exists correctly in both English and Russian. However, in Sonata Admin, it only displays the English translation, even though the session language is switched to Russian.

Here is the connection:

[image]

[image]

HeaderAdmin.php

```
final class HeaderAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $list): void
    {

        $list
            ->add('title')
            ->add('text')
            ->add('image')
            ->add(ListMapper::NAME_ACTIONS, null, [
                'actions' => [
                    'show' => [],
                    'edit' => [],
                    'delete' => [],
                ],
            ]);
    }

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $form): void
    {
        $form
            ->add('title')
            ->add('text')
            ->add('image')
            ;
    }

    protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $show): void
    {
        $show
            ->add('title')
            ->add('text')
            ->add('image')
            ;
    }
}
```

and header translation entity

```
#[ORM\Entity]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'header_translation')]
#[ORM\UniqueConstraint(name: 'header_translation_idx', columns: ['locale', 'object_id', 'field'])]
class HeaderTranslation extends AbstractPersonalTranslation
{
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Header::class, inversedBy: 'translations')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'object_id', onDelete: 'cascade')]
    protected $object;
}
```